# Silverlight 4 - Out of Browser Applications

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Does a Silverlight 4 out of browser application have access to the .NET Framework?

Comment: What part of the .NET Framework do you want access to?

Comment: @ChrisF - All of it would be nice. We're considering SL 4 for LOB apps. Not having access to the .NET Framework would seem to be a severe limitation.

Comment: The answer is "it depends" - as Anthony as pointed out you need Elevated Trust for OOB applications, but Colin is also correct in that Silverlight is based on a cut down version of the Framework. What do you want to do?

Comment: The company I'm working for is writing a LOB application in SL4 using WCF RIA Services to communicate with the DB. We haven't hit anything that's stopped us doing what we want to do.

Comment: @ChrisF - Is this because you've kept your SL UI very lightweight and most of the heavy lifting is in server code, where you have access to the full .NET Framework?

Comment: @Randy - not particularly. We're using Prism MVVM and Infragistics for some controls (grids mainly). What **exactly** is it that you want to do that you think is lacking? We're not accessing the local file system (but we don't need to).

Comment: @ChrisF - I can't tell you exactly what we want to do. We're simply evaluating Silverlight for some corporate LOB applications. At a high level, we're going to want to do what you might typically do in a LOB application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word: No.   There is an exception.  When the application is installed as having Elevated Trust then COM Visible and creatable portions of the .NET Framework may be accessed.

Comment: Is this also true with Silverlight 4 browser apps?

Comment: @Randy: no. SL4 Apps and SL4 OOB without elevated trust cannot use COM directly.  Of course in IE the ActiveXObject class is available which can construct COM objects which are marked safe for scriping.  None of the COM objects in the .NET Framework are so marked, however its still possible to build a COM Visible assembly that is marked safe for scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ... and so do in-browser applications! Silverlight out-of-browser applications do not have any significant extra frameworks available to them. Silverlight uses a subset of the .NET framework. If you are interested in whether a specific framework feature is available, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

No. Long answer: There are at least two completely different branches of the .NET Framework. The desktop/server ones which are the ones you want access to and the Silverlight ones which include the Windows Phone and XNA branches.

It is possible to write libraries that work with both branches of frameworks in binary form, but they cannot use any API save very fundamental stuff. Especially UI and IO is off limits. So in practice, you have two worlds that are incompatible on a binary level. This is very sad, but that's how it is and it can't changed without breaking backward compatibility.

So as others said, even with elevated privileges, you need to write a separate software in the main .NET framework and communicate with it over COM or Silverlight's host environment.